# render component in mat-sidenav-content

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I created an angular material sidenav with the following HTML template:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav>
 <!--menu component added here-->
</mat-sidenav>

<mat-sidenav-content>
  <app-home></app-home>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

When the template is loaded for the first time the app-home component will be rendered. When a menu item is selected the relevant component will be rendered in the mat-sidenav-component but the app-home will still appear. Can I hide it when a menu item is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to my misunderstanding of te question i've made a last edit.

**As introduction info:** the method is the same if you are using Angualr or Angular Material.

**EDIT:** Here you can see same method applied to Angular Material: [Stack blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk7bxg-3mxrwn)

**ORIGINAL:**
Yes your menu component have to send a `boolean` input to your page container with `eventEmitter`, so when the page has loaded the default state of the input is `true` and when the menu item is clicked the input state will change to `false` and the `app-home` will be hide.

Your **page container** (or sidenav main component) will be like this

```
// Imports omitted
@Component({
  selector: 'page-container',
  template: `
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">Lorem ipsum</mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
         <menu-component (show)="show($event)" (hide)="hide($event)"></menu-component>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
         <app-home [toggle]="visible"></app-home>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>`
  })

export class PageContainerPage {

    visible: boolean;

    show(event: boolean) {
      this.visible = event;
    }

    hide(event: boolean) {
      this.visible = event;
    }

}
```

Your **menu** component will be like this - used here [event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) and [output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output)

```
// Imports omitted
@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  template: `
      <ul>
        <li (click)="showElement()">menu item 1</li>
        <li (click)="hideElement()">menu item 2</li>
      </ul>`
})

export class MenuComponent {
    showHideBoolean: boolean; // Just delete default value

    // Output to send
    @Output() show: EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
    @Output() hide: EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();

    showHideElement(){
      console.log('you have click on a menu item')
      this.showHideBoolean = !this.showHideBoolean;

      if (this.showHideBoolean) {
         this.show.emit(true);
         console.log('value to send: ', this.showHideBoolean) 
      } else {
         this.hide.emit(false);
         console.log('value to send: ', this.showHideBoolean) 
      }
    }
}
```

Your **app-home** component will be like this - used here [input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="toggle">I'm the first element</div>
    <div [ngClass]="{'color-red' : toggle}">I'm the second element!</div>
    <div *ngIf="toggle">I'm an element too!</div>`
})

export class AppHomeComponent {

    // Use @Import here
    @Input() toggle: Boolean; // Just remove the default value

}
```

Comment: Hello Emanuele, thanks for you answer. The side-nav component i am using is one single angular material basic sidenav component (see https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview). I only want to show and hide the app-home component. I thought it could be done like you suggest but can't figure out where is should put the event emitter

Comment: Hi @Elias maybe i've misunderstanding your question. What component do you want to hide when you click on an element inside the `menu-component` ? I've change the answer to hide the `app-home` component

Comment: Hello Emanuele, maybe my question wasn't clear and i rephrased it a bit :) The component i want to hide is the app-home component Based on you answer i emit an event in the navbar.component.ts when a menu option is clicked, but i can't read the value in the parent component

Comment: Obviously you can use other techniques from RxJS like `BehaviorSubject ` or `Observables` but `@Output` and `EventEmitter` is the unique that doesn't involve the use of external libraries

Comment: it is not working 100%. i am confused somehow. Something doesn't fit. When the same button is clicked the showHideBoolean variable changes

Comment: Solved by following Emanuele's proposal with a small modification. I used two different functions for each emitted instead of one because when clicking again on the same menu option the result was changed (showHideBoolean had a new value which leaded to the wring emit) and left the app-home unchanged. I also modified the answer accordingly

Comment: @Elias i've review your edit. To avoid the unchanged effect just remove the default value form `showHideBoolean: boolean;` and form `@Input() toggle: Boolean`. I've also update the link to the **stackblitz** example! Now you can open it in editor! Sorry for the inconvenience!